# Single ZFS Checksum error on mirror, sounds improbable to me

Tags: linux, zfs

I have a ZFS pool with the following layout and errors:

```
config:

NAME                                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
tank                                             ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-0                                          ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x5000039ff3d3b114-part2                    ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x5000039ff4d3b513-part1                    ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-1                                          ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x5000c500a42783bc-part1                    ONLINE       0     0     2
    wwn-0x5000c500a426d50b-part1                    ONLINE       0     0     2

errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

    tank/foo/bar@veryOldSnapshot;corruptFile.qcow2
```

So it looks as if on two different devices the same record has been corrupted at the same time. The data in question is on this disks since 2019 and the pool is scrubbed every week. How are the chances? IMHO this cannot be a real "bits are flipped due to cosmical radiation or hdd failure" case, because the probability that exactly the same blocks are corrupted on both disks and no other block is are really low.

What else can have caused this? I ran memtestx86 without problems and scrubbing again does not find any other errors. However since the block is used in a long chain of snapshots, even removing the snapshot in question does just make the problem move to the next snapshot.

Comment: The most likely explanation I can think of is that either the data or its checksum was corrupted in RAM prior to being written to disk. So ZFS detects the corruption but can't fix it because all versions of the block are corrupt. But you would expect the earlier scrubs to catch it in that case.

Comment: Another possibility is that you were reading from the block on both disks at the same time, and something happened to both disks simultaneously which caused them to mess up the data underneath the head. That seems pretty unlikely though because even very small time differences would be enough that they weren't synchronized on the same block.